# Ruby on Rails fullcalendar-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use bokmann/fullcalendar-rails.
It is gem for using arshaw/fullcalendar.

I have the sample app with Sqlite working on my iMac. When I get the code into my own app, the calendar displays fine except I don't see any events.

Questions:
1) Should Postgres work just the same as Sqlite or do I need to make some adjustment?
2) Is it ok to have a few extra fields in the Events table as long as I have all the required fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.  The first was from the sample code and it worked with Sqlite but not Postgres. The second line works.

```
 scope :between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
{:conditions => ["? < starts_at < ?", Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)] }


scope :between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
{:conditions => ["? < starts_at and starts_at < ?", Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)] }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

postgres should work the same as Sqlite - you shouldn't have to make any changes to the app as long as you do everything through the Rails framework.

Does the sample app come with some example events in the seeds file that you need to import into your new app? Have you actually got any events in your new app that you should be seeing? Load up the Rails console and see whats in the table if in doubt:

```
rails console
Event.all # or whatever your model is called.
```

... and see what comes back.

Comment: No seeds in the sample app.  I have 5 records in the Events table that should be showing up in the Calendar.